# Colour nodes in D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a D3 noob and looking for help on how to colour named nodes in a D3 Force layout. In the code below, the number of nodes are defined as 200, and the sub_classes are first named as `"p"` and `"o"`. And then the `makeData` function makes the 200 nodes, randomly assigning to `"p"` or `"o"`.

```
var colors = {p: "#99CC00", o: "steelblue"},
  radius = 7,
  node_count = 200,
  classes = "a".split(""),
  sub_classes = "po".split("");

function makeData(){
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < node_count; i++){
    out.push({
      id: i,
      class: classes[jz.num.randBetween(0, classes.length - 1)],
      sub_class: sub_classes[jz.num.randBetween(0, sub_classes.length - 1)]
    });
  }
  return out;
}
```

I would like to change the random assignmnet. In the `makeData` function, I would like to make 20% of the nodes the `"p"` sub_class and 80% of the nodes the `"o"` sub_class. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function to return `0` or `1` according to the predefined chances, using `Math.random()`. There are clever ways to do this, but here I'm writing a verbose function just to be more didactic.

The function can be something like this:

```
function myRandomNumber(lim) {
  var random = Math.random();
  if (random < lim) {
    return 0
  } else {
    return 1
  }
}
```

Where the argument is the limit of the result of `Math.random()`, which goes from 0 to 1 (conveniently, 0 is 0% and 1 is 100%).

So, in your case, you would call it with:

```
sub_class: sub_classes[myRandomNumber(0.2)];
```

Here is a basic demo, calling the function 100 times:

```js
var sub_classes = ["p", "o"];

function myRandomNumber(lim) {
  var random = Math.random();
  if (random < lim) {
    return 0
  } else {
    return 1
  }
}

var counter = {
  p: 0,
  o: 0
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  counter[sub_classes[myRandomNumber(0.2)]]++
}

console.log(counter)
```